# How to select an area of an image displayed in a canvas (like in paint) and then move the selection

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas

I need to select an area of an image displayed inside a canvas, and after that, the selection could be moved around the canvas.
Javascript will be ideal, no jquery

[image]

Basically, I use mousedown and click events to get the coordinates of the cropping/selecting area

I hope that black rect on the right photo can be seen. I try to make that rectangle moveable and resizable to get the coordinates of the selected area, not just from the 2 events from before. Just like it is in Paint. Sorry for the late edit

Comment: Please share your attempt

Comment: Please show us what you've done so far.

Comment: The problem is that I don`t know how to approach this, I'm new to js, so sorry

Answer (score 1):

```css
#container {
  background-color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="container" width="500" height="500" onmousedown="drag(event);" onmouseup="drop(event);"></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
  }
  function draw(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById("container");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    for (var i = 0; i <= 450; i += 50)
      for (var j = 0; j < 450; j += 50) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(i, j, 50, 50);
        ctx.fillStyle = getRandomColor();
        ctx.fill();
      }
  } // end draw
  function drag(ev) {
    drag.offsetX = ev.offsetX;
    drag.offsetY = ev.offsetY;
  }

  function drop(ev) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("container");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.putImageData(ctx.getImageData(drag.offsetX, drag.offsetY, 10, 10), ev.offsetX, ev.offsetY);
  }
  
  draw();

</script>
```

The snippet above draws a canvas, filling it with squares of randomized color and then supports drag & drop. You will need to enhance the size of regions you are dragging and add some further controls, but this is a good starting point for your work.

Comment: Thank you, this definitively will help me, with the other tasks

Comment: @VictorMitoi you are welcome!